# alt description only appearing for the first image in a v-for

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using the [Unsplash API](https://unsplash.com/developers) to make an app and I have an image tag within a vuejs `v-for` and an alt description for the *first* image appears fine, but after that, the alt description for the rest of the images are null.

Here is some code:

```
<div v-for="photo in photos" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 image-column" :key="photo.id">
  <nuxt-link :to="`/photos/${photo.id}`">
    <div class="image-grid position-relative">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail lazyload w-100" :data-src="photo.urls.thumb" :alt="photo.alt_description" />
        <app-image-meta :photo="photo"></app-image-meta>
    </div>
  </nuxt-link>
</div>
```

Here is how I get the photo's data:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
const access_token = 'xxx'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Client-ID ${access_token}`

import appImageGrid from '../components/image-grid.vue'

export default {
  async asyncData( { params, store } ) {
    let { data } = await axios.get(`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?page=${params.num ? params.num : 1}&per_page=12`)
    return { photos: data }
  },
  components: {
    appImageGrid
  }
}
</script>
```

I checked my *Postman* and all the images have an alt description so that's not a problem there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So I just checked the Vue dev-tools and yes, the `alt_description` for the first one shows up just fine, but then shows up as `null` for the rest

Comment: I'm using an `async asyncData` method provided by Nuxt. From there, I get the photo's objects with its id, alt description, image, etc. and put them in a property called `photo`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you see the request in your browser's _Network_ console? If so, does the response look right? Does each entry in the array have all the properties you expect?

Comment: Hey Phil. Alright, I'm not sure if you're gonna hate me or not, but I just realized that from the three batches of photos I was looking at, the first one had an alt description and the rest _intentionally_ didn't have an alt description (from the author itself). The code is correct. Sorry to have wasted your time my apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I just realized that the batches of photos I was looking at the first one had an alt description, but the rest strangely had *null* as an alt description. After digging a bit and looking at *more* batches of photos, I realized late that the alt descriptions for the previous batches were intentionally not written by the author. Appreciate your help, Phil.